# Как удалить лишние символы из json файла?

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения, json

Есть json файл, к примеру:

`
лишние символы {

}лишние символы [{

}] лишние символы`

Как удалить все "лишние символы", пробовал так, но работает неправильно

```
Regex reg = new Regex(@"[^\{^}^\w^\[^\]^,^""^:]*");
```

и как еще удалить null символы ?

Comment: Боюсь, что регэкспами вашу задачу так просто не решить - JSON допускает произвольный уровень вложенности конструкций. Можно попробовать реализовать конечный автомат, который будет отслеживать текущую позицию в потоке (внутри словаря/списка или снаружи) и пропускать символы, находящееся вне допустимых позиций.

Comment: не совсем коректно изложил вопрос, нужно удалить все ASCII символы .

Comment: @eigenein, произвольный уровень вложенности для регулярных выражений не проблема.  
@cyber_ya, изложите мысль ясно, последовательно и выпукло: пример текста, желаемый результат, описание как был получен результат.

Comment: @ReinRaus , есть бинарный файл , для его чтения использую ASCII, но проблема в том что остаются лишние символы, если открыть его с помощью notepad++ то видно что это за символы ETX(end of text), NULL,.. 
Мне нужно их по удалять из строки в которую я считал с файла.

Comment: выложите свой бинарный файл куда-нибудь и ссылку в ответ.

Comment: @ReinRaus , вот https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=E8788102BA5E11A5!603&authkey=!AAiaYDGob8Xf5fE

Comment: не мучайте себя, http://forum.worldoftanks.eu/index.php?/topic/185348-082-wot-replay-analyzer/

Comment: @petya, я не мучаю, я учу C# и просто делаю тестовый проект что бы лучше понять принцип работы с файлами, а так как давно хотел сортировку сделать не на батниках, вот и взялся .

Comment: @ReinRaus, [JSON - не регулярный язык](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/3987/is-json-a-regular-language).

Comment: @eigenein: вы и правы и не правы. Современные регулярные выражения умеют парсить нерегулярные языки, это да. (Мне на это @ReinRaus как-то недавно обратил внимание; пользуясь случаем, спасибо!) Но тем не менее корректный парсинг сколько-нибудь сложной грамматики на регулярках всё равно необычайно сложен и совершенно не поддаётся отладке. Так что я бы не рекомендовал использовать регулярные выражения для JSON (как и, например, для HTML).

Comment: @cyber_ua: Мне кажется, ваш подход неверен. Вы не можете формально выяснить, где же начинается JSON, потому что в окружающем тексте присутствуют произвольные символы. Например, следующий текст:

    (это случайный текст вокруг)lalafa={"(текст вокруг кончился, дальше валидный JSON)

не поймается -- видите, почему? Вам нужно узнать формат всего файла, распарсить его, и нацеленно выдрать интересующие вас куски.

Comment: Сделал комментарием, потому что не полностью совместимы выражения PHP и С# в части рекурсий.  Ввиду отсутствия С# не могу переделать сам, но может любой желающий прочитав статью  
 http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bs2twtah.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Вот здесь пример того, как с такими файлами работают: [тык](http://pastebin.com/UZadNsPc).

Для работы с JSON используется библиотека [Json.NET](http://json.codeplex.com/)

**ОБНОВЛЕНИЕ #0**

упрощенный пример:

```
public void Read(string filename)
{
    if (!File.Exists(filename)) return;

    BinaryReader binaryReader = new BinaryReader(
        new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read));
    binaryReader.ReadInt64();
    Encoding defaultEncoding = Encoding.Default;

    int count1 = binaryReader.ReadInt32();
    string str = defaultEncoding.GetString(binaryReader.ReadBytes(count1));

    binaryReader.Close();

    JObject obj1 = JObject.Parse(str);

    Console.WriteLine(filename);
    Console.WriteLine(obj1.ToString());
}
```

Comment: я и так использую эту библиотеку , но проблема в том что файл не парситься пока не убрать лишние сиволы...

Comment: у меня для тебя плохие новости, там все парсится, тебе даже пример привели, ты смотрел его?
http://imgur.com/M3cmq

Comment: вот код,
`
  StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"C:\winTest.wotreplay", Encoding.ASCII);

            json = sr.ReadLine();

         //   json = json.Remove(0, json.IndexOf("{"));

            JObject o = JObject.Parse(json);


            JToken[] players = o["vehicles"].ToArray();


            foreach (JToken pl in players)
            {

                richTextBox1.AppendText(pl+"\n" );
             
            }
`
если я беру чистый json, то все ок, а если беру с символами , то не работает...

Comment: Дело в том, что там не чистый JSON, а блоки информации (часть которых содержат JSON).
Про структуру файла можно почитать по ссылкам:
http://forum.worldoftanks.eu/index.php?/topic/114016-the-wot-072-and-073-replay-file-format-explained/
http://forum.worldoftanks.eu/index.php?/topic/105682-wot-replay-file-format/

Comment: "что там не чистый JSON" - ну это и ежику понятно)
Я пытаюсь обрезать все кроме json.
За ссылки спс, потом гляну.

Comment: Ну так надо честно распарсить формат. Потому что чисто синтаксически кусок с json нельзя отделить от куска без него. Халявы не будет, надо делать правильно.